# properly using jQuery Mobile event handling in version 1.7.1

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am at my wits end with jQuery Mobile events. I do not understand them, despite following the docs to the T. I am using the following code to initialize my pages. The problem is that some seem to fire multiple times and occasionally when I go back to a page nothing will appear, as though .live pageinit simply doesn't fire at all. I am quite confused. Is pageinit the way to go? is .live best practice? Do I need to clean up after myself and use something like pagehide to remove stuff from the DOM? Please help me understand. Thanks!

```
// page number 1
<header>
   includes and stuff
<header>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="dashboardPage">
        $('#dashboardPage').live('pageinit',function() {

        });

        // somewhere in here a page transition to anotherPage.html (not necessarily the id of the new page in the <div data-role-"page data-theme...> declaration

        $.mobile.changePage("anotherPage.html",{transition : "slide"});

    </div>
</body>

// page number 2
<header>
   includes and stuff
<header>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="specialsPage">
        $('#specialsPage').live('pageinit',function() {

        });
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <!--  BASIC INCLUDES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <!--  END - BASIC INCLUDES -->

    </header>
    <body>
        <!--  PAGE 1 -->
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="dashboardPage">
            <script>
                // INITIALIGE PAGE 1 -  dashboardPage
                $("#dashboardPage").live('pageinit',function(event){
                    alert( '"initializing" page 1: dashboardPage');
                });
            </script>

            HERE YOU ARE AT PAGE 1 (dashboardPage)!!!<br><br>
            <a href="#specialsPage" data-transition="pop">CLICK HERE TO GO TO PAGE 2 (specialsPage)</a>
        </div>

        <!--  PAGE 2 -->
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="specialsPage">
            <script>
                // INITIALIGE PAGE 2 -  specialsPage
                $("#specialsPage").live('pageinit',function(event){
                    alert( '"initializing" page 2: specialsPage');
                });
            </script>

            HERE YOU ARE AT PAGE 2 (specialsPage)!!!<br><br>
            <a href="#dashboardPage" data-transition="slide">CLICK HERE TO GO TO PAGE 1 (dashboardPage)</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When using JQuery mobile you should consider you have a single page which content is updated dynamically. You do not navigate from one page to the other as you normally would.
Because of this, any code present in a page you navigate to with JQM simply be ignored (tyr changing the header of page number 2, and navigate to this page from page number 1 with changepage, you will not see any difference).
Because of that, all your js code should be directly available within the page in which your user will arrive.

If you add the following code in the scripts of page 1, you will proeperly detect the initialization of of page2 when it is loaded with changepage.

```
$("#specialsPage").live('pageinit',function(event){
                alert( '"initializing" page 2: specialsPage');
});
```

An important thing to keep in mind is that you user might also directly access your page2, which means that all the code should also be available for page 2. Because of this I would strongly recommend including all your code in a js file referenced in the headers of all your page, and NOT directly in script tags within your pages.

Comment: how do you do a universal include for a file? Could I put all of my javascript includes in there as well as my css includes? Probably not, right...

Comment: You can include all the links to CSS and js files in the header of your first page. Any page navigates from there through jquerymobile will benefit from them.

Comment: Check the end of te answer: all files should be referenced in the headers of all pages the user may directly head to